# Redefining a singleton_class method to behave exactly as it was behaving before but also do something else

Tags: ruby

I want to change a singleton_class method of a certain class for it to do the same as it was doing before but also do something else, For example apart from what it was doing, to do:

- puts "hello"

Ok, so i know how to redefine a normal method of a class to actually do the same as it was doing before but also do something else, it would be like this:

```
class Class
   def addHelloToMethod(methodName)
       unboundMethod = instance_method(methodName)

       define_method(methodName) do |*args, &block|

          result =unboundMethod.bind(self).(*args, &block)
          puts "hello"
          result
      end
   end
end
```

What i need is to actually add this "hello" to a singleton_class method
so i tried this:

```
class Class
   def addHelloToSingletonClassMethod(methodName)
       unboundMethod = singleton_class.instance_method(methodName)

       singleton_class.define_method(methodName) do |*args, &block|

          result =unboundMethod.bind(self).(*args, &block)
          puts "hello"
          result
      end
   end
end
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is to prepend an anonymous module that overrides the desired method, prints hello, and calls `super` to invoke the actual implementation.

I'm not sure why you're adding this method to `Class`. Is your goal to call the `addHelloToSingletonClassMethod` on an instance of a class such as this?

```
irb> s = "foo"
irb> s.addHelloToSingletonClassMethod(:upcase)
irb> s.upcase
hello
=> "FOO"
```

If so, define the following on `Object`:

```
class Object
   def addHelloToSingletonClassMethod(methodName)
     mod = Module.new
     mod.define_method(methodName) do |*args, &blk|
       puts "hello"
       super(*args, &blk)
     end

     singleton_class.prepend(mod)
   end
end
```

Or in more typical Ruby naming convention:

```
class Object
  def add_hello_to_method(name)
    mod = Module.new
    mod.define_method(name) do |*args, &blk|
      puts "hello"
      super(*args, &blk)
    end

    singleton_class.prepend(mod)
  end
end
```

If your goal on the other hand is to be able to call it on a class as follows

```
irb> String.addHelloToSingletonClassMethod(:upcase)
irb> "foo".upcase
hello
=> "FOO"
```

then you want to define it on `Class`:

```
class Class
  def add_hello_to_method(name)
    mod = Module.new
    mod.define_method(name) do |*args, &blk|
      puts "hello"
      super(*args, &blk)
    end

    prepend(mod)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change change `addHelloToSingletonClassMethod` to `self.addHelloToSingletonClassMethod`. It should be a class method.

Comment: That would define a method in Class singleton_class, i want to redefine a method in a Class instance singleton_class.